# I am trying to add an assigned variable to a list on python, it is in a while loop so I want it to keep adding the variable

Tags: python

I hoped that made sense anyways, here is the code

```
guess = input("Pick a letter")       # Asks the user for a letter
guess = guess.upper()                # Changes the variable to uppercase
guesses = [guess]                    # I want this to put every guess in in the 
                                     #   list, then display it
print("You have guessed" + guesses)  # Shows the variable, all this code is in a 
                                     #   while loop
```

Anyway Ihope you understand this, the code is in a while loop but the all of the code is not needed and the while loop has a set condition to something else, this is not the issue. Just want the variable 'guess' in a list so that everytime asked the variable will be added

Comment: do `guesses = []; guesses.append(guess)` to put them into a list. And may I recomend that you go through the official [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), everything you need to know is covered there in the list section

Answer (score 1):

You can create the `guesses` list *before* the loop, and then append to it within the loop:

```
guesses = []
while someCondition:
    guess = input('something')
    guesses.append(guess)

print('You have guessed:', guesses)
```

Comment: Hmm. Comes up with can't convert list object into str

Comment: Now it goes off the while loop when you input something

Comment: At what point? You can’t do `"You have guessed" + guesses`, as `guesses` is a list, and you can’t concat a string and a list. That’s why I used `print('You have guessed:', guesses)` (note the comma). Other than that, you could also do `"You have guessed" + str(guesses)`.